# APP crashes on clicking the Intent button

Tags: android, kotlin

I am new to Android Studio and Kotlin. I am making budget tracking APP but it keeps crashing on clicking the button that should take it to the next activity screen.
Error is coming as
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.budgettracker/com.example.budgettracker.AddTransactionActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageButton cannot be cast to android.widget.Button

Main Activity:

```
        binding.addBtn.setOnClickListener {
            val intent: Intent = Intent(this, AddTransactionActivity::class.java).also {
                startActivity(it)
            }
        }
```

It is also showing this in error:
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageButton cannot be cast to android.widget.Button
at com.example.budgettracker.AddTransactionActivity.onCreate(AddTransactionActivity.kt:39)
and line 39 in AddTransactionActivity.kt is

AddTransactionActivity.kt

```
findViewById<Button>(R.id.closeBtn).setOnClickListener {
    finish()
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.BudgetTracker"
        tools:targetApi="31">
        <activity
            android:name=".AddTransactionActivity"
            android:exported="false" />
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

The app crashes on clicking the button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is `findViewById<Button>`. You should use `findViewById<AppCompatImageButton>` instead, or change the XML so that the `closeBtn` id resolves to a `Button`.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your generic `<Button>` to `<ImageButton>` in `findViewById`. Let me explain some details of the exception you received.

You got: ".`..java.lang.ClassCastException: androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageButton cannot be cast to android.widget.Button`".

The point is that in the XML file, I think you have used an `<ImageButton>`. And in the Kotlin code you want to say that this `<ImageButton>` is just a `<Button>`, which of course is not true - `java.lang.ClassCastException`.

I would do it this way:

```
findViewById<ImageButton>(R.id.closeBtn).setOnClickListener {... Your code here ...}
```

Good luck!